# Why case class and object with different names appear in same scala file?

Tags: scala, class, object

I am new to scala and confused about why case class and object with different names appear in same scala file? As far as I know, we can put object and class in the same `.scala` file with same name to make a `companion object`. But in the example they are different.Here is some example code in `WikipediaRanking.scala`:

```
case class WikipediaArticle(title: String, text: String) {

}

object WikipediaRanking extends WikipediaRankingInterface {
}
```

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html

Comment: Differently to **Java**, the **Scala** spec doesn't force only one class per file and thus it doesn't force the class and the file to be named the same. It is indeed common and standard to only place a single class / trait / object and its companion in a file with the same name. However, it is also common to having `util` or `model` or `errors` files that contains a bunch of case classes.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Java doesn't force only one class per file either. It's true about **public** classes.